# Java process hangs after executing Oracle stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle

I have a batch process written in Java 6 with `ojdbc6` driver (previously `ojdbc5`) connecting to Oracle 11g. It hangs on `executeupdate()` method. The method executes the Stored Procedure for more than an hour.

After the Stored Procedure has updated some necessary tables and committed the transaction, it never goes back to the java caller of `executeupdate()`. It works on test server but it hangs on production server.

I suspected the ojdbc driver before but after upgrading it to ojdbc6 the issue still persists.

Comment: how long it took to run the SP manually ?

Comment: the same as it was called by java program.

Comment: Did running it on the test server also take more than an hour?

Comment: yeah, 1 and 20 minutes to be precise. It works for years and then suddenly it hangs for few months now.

Comment: that implies you have to fine tune your stored procedures queries. Check for proper index & performance hints.

Comment: i think the amount of time is reasonable as it iterates almost 70,000 records, additional index might help to reduce the execution time but i believe issue will not resolve.

Comment: Is it trying to update something that is locked by another session, maybe?

Comment: at the end of stored proc it has a log which means it reached the end of the procedure. It use cursor and im not sure this causes the lock to other tables.

Comment: Just want to share my resolution to this issue, rewriting the procedure and removing the cursor fixed it. I don't know what's wrong with the cursor. hope this helps.

Comment: @fuzzy28  If you fixed it yourself, you should add your own answer and accept yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to share my resolution to this issue, rewriting the procedure and removing the cursor fixed it. I don't know what's wrong with the cursor. hope this helps.

Comment: Any chance you have now an idea why it worked ? :) I have the same issue which seems to come and go and I do not know why.

Comment: Hmm I actually don't remember lol, but you can try to avoid using cursor.